# adding scrollable stock chart in excel -export

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, candlestick-chart

i want to export candlestick chart (stock chart excel) to excel (c#- epplus): stock chart (open-high-low-close)

since the data is date-wise ( I've restricted to a year only.)
wen chart (candle stick) is drawn into excel, its like compressed one, to view it properly, i may need to have a zoom effect/ or scroll-able chart or the best to stretch it very wide according to the width

m looking to have scroll-able chart coding for excel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial about this recently: [Chart Partial Range Between Variable Endpoints](http://peltiertech.com/chart-range-endpoints/)